# Error 404 in Eclipse while running Servlets on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I am trying to execute a simple servlet on Apache Tomcat using the Eclipse IDE.
The servlet itself is executing, but when I try to invoke the html form through which I will pass user data to the servlet, I get Error 404.
Is my approach incorrect ?

Update 1:
File web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>assign3_servlets</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>clientFile.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DbServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.appperfect.training.DbServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DbServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DbServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

File clientFile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JDBC - Servlets</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<form action="DbServlet" method="post" >
<table>
<tr>
    <td>JDBC Driver</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="jdbc_driver" size="30"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>JDBC URL</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="jdbc_url" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="uname" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" id="pass" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Query</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="query" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td ><input type="submit" id="submit_query"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please post your `web.xml` and `.html` file containing form.

Comment: Your approach to asking this question is incorrect. How do you know "the servlet itself is executing"? What URL are you accessing and what is in your web.xml file? Have you actually added the web application to Tomcat in Eclipse, and are you sure the Tomcat instance is synchronized and everything is published?

Comment: When I run the servlet on tomcat, it shows. printWriter() statements are showing on the server.
but when I run the html file first, I get Error 404.
The Server is synchronized and running.

Answer (score 0):

With every mapping being rightly done, I mistakenly placed the file in the wrong folder.
Now everything is working fine.